# If $a<c $ for each $c>b$ then $a\le b$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. If $a<c $ for each $c>b$, prove that $a\le b.$

I have tried the method of contradiction but I have failed to get the results.

I have assumed $a>b$, then if $a<c$ and $c>b$, I don't know if I can contradict anything.
Should I assume that $a-b<\epsilon$?

Comment: Show your working please even if you fail to get the results.

Comment: I have tried to assume a>b, then if a<c and c>b, I don't know if I can contradict anything.

Comment: In the question, show them in the question.

Answer (score 5):

We can prove it by the method of contradiction. Suppose otherwise that $a > b$, then $a < a$, contradiction. Thus $a \leq b$.

Comment: How can we say that a<a?

Comment: Its because if $ \triangle > b $ then $a < \triangle$. The $\triangle = a$ in this case.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: @KaushikDas take a close look at the hypotheses in your question.  Compare the hypotheses in your question to DeepSea's comment above.

Comment: I got you, many thanks @DeepSea

Answer (score 2):

Suppose on the contrary that $a>b$, then $$b<\frac{a+b}{2}<a$$

Do you see a contradiction?

Comment: So I have to assume a-b<€ and €=(a+b)/2?

Comment: I am just showing a possible way to obtain a contradiction. Deepsea's approach is even cooler.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a>b$ and $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Can you get a contradiction from here?